# Can I register myself as CEO for my freelancing company besides being a regular full time employee in a Corporate

Tags: registration

I am working for an MNC in India and do sparetime freelancing jobs. I had worked for some 4-5 clients and got the payment transferred to my personal account.

I recently did my biggest project till date and they are asking my business account to transfer the payment(I donot have Business account)

Opening a business bank account requires registration and registration needs a CEO and Director. Everything seems good but I am not sure whether I can register myself as CEO of my own company while I am a full time employee of another company.

Any Advises on this please :(

Comment: Seems to me this would be a **legal question** in your country which is not directly related to freelancing.

Comment: There is a [meta discussion](http://meta.freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/135/legal-questions-on-topic-or-not) about this question; please read and post your opinion on this type of question for the future

Comment: Hey Lisbeth, are you a freelancer in the freelancing company? Could you add in why you can't just take a check or use something like Paypal? This will help folks better understand your problem. Hope this helps! :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Freelance Consulting while Employed](http://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/603/freelance-consulting-while-employed)

Comment: Isn't easier that you simply tell them that you do not have company registered in your own country and ask them to pay you to some e-wallet or to your own bank account?

Comment: Peter - companies do not like paying self-employed (or non-employee) people direct, as they do not wish to he designated as a direct employer.

Answer (score 2):

The question "whether I can register myself as CEO of my own company while I am a full time employee of another company" boils down to what you have agreed in your contract of employment with the other company.

See also: [Freelance Consulting while Employed](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/603/freelance-consulting-while-employed)

Fundamentally, there is not usually a legal obstacle to holding down two employments - as long as the tax authorities get their cut - whether the second job is a second employment, or as self-employed or freelancer.

If there was such an obstacle, then I suggest that a significant proportion of freelancers would have a problem.

However, your contract of employment may place restrictions on outside interests, especially if in a related field to your day-job - in such instances talk to your manager (or the HR department).

Answer (score 0):

You should consult a legal advisor for this. This is a strictly a legal issue.

In my country [a small European country, Croatia] you cannot "sit on two chairs" e.g. cannot be full-time employed in one company and be CEO in another. But I think some other countries allow this. Maybe India allows as well.

Comment: Peter, after "in my country" could you add your country in brackets?

Answer (score 0):

I registered myself as a CEO of the company in the start of my freelance business. At that time I had an office address where I used to work. Currently all my payments are coming to that account. I think that this is better to register yourself as a CEO of the company. This will be better for bigger transactions.